# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds in Depth First Search

Tags: java, stack, depth-first-search

I am currently running into an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception in my character array. I think I have multiple issues though. This program should solve a maze using a Stack class I created. These are my errors:

1.`LinkedStack` class prints "Stack is Empty" and "Nothing can be removed" which I am not sure if it is being caused by the Index error or something else.

2.`IndexOutOfBoundsException` which I think is occurring due to a minor logic error.

I am currently using someone else's algorithm simply because I have done this before but in a different manner. I am not quite sure what is causing the errors, I am guessing that I am trying to access a location that is outside of the maze. The exception occurs at the lines where maze is passed and the value of the `IndexOutOfBounds` is -1.

**Sample Maze (s = start, f = finish, * = wall)**

```
*****
*s* *
* * *
*  f*
*****
```

**My LinkedStack Class**

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class LinkedStack {
private Node top;

public LinkedStack() {
    top = null;
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return top == null;
}
public void push( Point p ) {
    top = new Node (p, top);
}
public Point pop() {
    Point retVal = new Point(0,0);
    if( isEmpty() ){
        System.out.println("Nothing to remove");
    }else{
        retVal = top.getValue();
        top = top.getNext();
    }
    return retVal;
}
public Point peek() {
    Point retVal = new Point(0,0);
    if( isEmpty() ){
        System.out.println("Stack is Empty");
    }else{
        retVal = top.getValue();
    }
    return retVal;
}
public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    Node n = top;
    while( n != null ){
        s = s + n.getValue() + " ";
        n = n.getNext();
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

**UPDATED Main, fixed IndexOutOfBounds now getting StackOverFlow**

```
//Creates an empty stack and calls method to get starting point
public static void solveDFS( char [][] maze ){
    LinkedStack stack = new LinkedStack();
    Point start = findPoint( maze,'s' );
    findPath( maze,start,stack );

}
//Finds the point of the start and finish by searching array
private static Point findPoint( char [][] maze, char c ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < maze[i].length; j++ ) {
            if ( maze[i][j] == c ) {
                return new Point(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
//Should mark location of path taken with '.'
//Should check neighboring spots of location (up,right,down,left)
//Should check if valid locations
public static boolean findPath( char [][] maze, Point location, LinkedStack stack ){
    boolean hasSolution = false;
    stack.push(location);

    do{
        maze[location.x][location.y] = '.';

        if( location.y > 0 ){
            if( maze[location.x][location.y - 1] == ' '){
                stack.push(new Point( location.x, location.y - 1));
                maze[location.x][location.y - 1] = '.';
            }
        }
        if( location.y < maze[location.x].length ){
            if( maze[location.x][location.y + 1] == ' '){
                stack.push(new Point( location.x, location.y + 1));
                maze[location.x][location.y + 1] = '.';
            }
        }
        if( location.x < maze.length ){
            if( maze[location.x + 1][location.y] == ' '){
                stack.push(new Point( location.x + 1, location.y ));
                maze[location.x + 1][location.y] = '.';
            }
        }
        if( location.x > 0 ){
            if( maze[location.x - 1][location.y] == ' '){
                stack.push(new Point( location.x - 1, location.y ));
                maze[location.x - 1][location.y] = '.';
            }
        }
        if( maze[location.x][location.y] == 'f' ){
             hasSolution = true;
        }

        location = stack.peek();
        stack.pop();
        findPath( maze,location,stack );
    }while( !location.equals('f') && !stack.isEmpty() );
    return hasSolution;
}
```

Comment: you will get IndexOutOfBoundsException  in statement `maze[location.x - 1][location.y]` when `location.x` will be 0.

Comment: you need to start loop variable value of `i and j from 1 not from 0` in `findPoint` method or change your logic to access `array` in `findPath` method

Comment: @Prashant I made these changes and I am still getting the same exception?

Comment: same is applicable for `y`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you try to get an index that might not be there, you should do boundary checks.

E.g. `maze[location.x][location.y + 1]` will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException if `y + 1 > maze[location.x].length`

**Update**: StackOverflow Exception.

I think this occurs because you always do the recursive `findPath` call *before* the condition of the while loop is evaluated. This means that you will never exit the do-while loop.

You need to add a condition that will terminate the recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

*(Note: I'm assuming top left of the maze is maze[0][0], and X is horizontal and Y is vertical.)*

Your core issue is not checking against being on the edge of the maze at these points:

```
    if( maze[location.x][location.y - 1] == ' '){
        stack.push(new Point( location.x, location.y - 1));
        maze[location.x][location.y - 1] = '.';
    }
```

^ This will fail if `location` is anywhere on the top edge of the maze.

```
    if( maze[location.x][location.y + 1] == ' '){
        stack.push(new Point( location.x, location.y + 1));
        maze[location.x][location.y + 1] = '.';
    }
```

^This will fail if `location` is anywhere on the bottom edge of the maze.

```
    if( maze[location.x + 1][location.y] == ' '){
        stack.push(new Point( location.x + 1, location.y ));
        maze[location.x + 1][location.y] = '.';
    }
```

^ This will fail if `location` is anywhere on the right edge of the maze.

```
    if( maze[location.x - 1][location.y] == ' '){
        stack.push(new Point( location.x - 1, location.y ));
        maze[location.x - 1][location.y] = '.';
    }
```

^ This will fail if `location` is anywhere on the left edge of the maze.

So you can wrap these 4 checks in checks of their own:

```
if(location.y > 0) {
    if( maze[location.x][location.y - 1] == ' '){
        stack.push(new Point( location.x, location.y - 1));
        maze[location.x][location.y - 1] = '.';
    }
}

if(location.y < maze[location.x].length) {
    if( maze[location.x][location.y + 1] == ' '){
        stack.push(new Point( location.x, location.y + 1));
        maze[location.x][location.y + 1] = '.';
    }
}

if(location.x < maze.length) {
    if( maze[location.x + 1][location.y] == ' '){
        stack.push(new Point( location.x + 1, location.y ));
        maze[location.x + 1][location.y] = '.';
    }
}

if(location.x > 0) {
    if( maze[location.x - 1][location.y] == ' '){
        stack.push(new Point( location.x - 1, location.y ));
        maze[location.x - 1][location.y] = '.';
    }
}
```

Now they'll only check adjacent tiles if they are logically able to.

Comment: I made these changes and I am no longer getting the IndexOutOfBoundsException. But I am now running into a new error which is StackOverFlow occurring in findPath() whenever the function calls itself. I have updated my code, not sure If you have an idea on the issue.